# String to JNI gets extra characters

Tags: java, string, java-native-interface

I am calling JNI method from Java app with couple of String arguments.
I am using `env->GetStringChars(arg1, 0 );` to get that strings. 
Problem is that I sometimes get some extra special characters or string is truncated.

Comment: What is 'env'? How do you pass the string to JNI function? What is that other language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution

```
const jchar* raw = env->GetStringChars(string, NULL);
if (raw == NULL)
    return NULL;

wchar_t* wsz = new wchar_t[len+1];
memcpy(wsz, raw, len*2);
wsz[len] = 0;

env->ReleaseStringChars(string, raw);

return wsz;
```

Comment: This won't work properly on platforms where `wchar_t` is larger than 2 bytes.

Comment: It is used on Win Mobile 6.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, chars are 16-bit characters (UTF-16 encoded).  If you treat them as a plain `char*` in C you will see nul bytes (which is usually treaded as the end of the String) or other special characters.

Perhaps you should use the UTF encoding which avoid nul char.  You will still need to handle special characters which are UTF encoded.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html

Comment: Using the `UTF` variants of JNI functions is almost always a bad idea, because they use a format that is not actually UTF-8. If you want to obtain a Java string's contents as a UTF-8 string, you should either get the `jchar` data and convert it yourself, or have the Java code encode the string into a UTF-8 `byte` array and access that instead.